# Print tibble with its rownames

Tags: r, tibble

I have a tibble:

```
tib = tibble(list(120,130,140), list("Jack", "John", "James"))
rownames(tib) = c("Observation1", "Observation2", "Observation3")   # displays deprecated warning on setting rownames,
                                      # this warning is ignorable for now
print(tib)                            # prints tibble, but not with the rownames
```

I’ve done some quick googles but see nothing. So offering this to the eternal quick-google search.

**How to print a tibble with its rownames that you explicitly have set?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  In case your wondering, I am trying to pretty-print a correlation matrix, which does have semantic meaning to its rownames — namely, the rownames and colnames are the same.

I simply want to name the rows and print them. I don’t think its possible, though, I will just convert back to base-R.

Comment: A tibble does *have* row names.

Comment: Maybe `colnames(tib) = c("Weight", "Name")`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, but they don’t print using `print(tib)`  >.<  I can convert back into base-R, but I see this as counter-productive to using tidyr in the first place.

Comment: @ppp The whole point is that *you should not use row names*, [the vignette explains why](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/tibble.html). But as noted in another comment your code doesn’t work anyway and, based on the names you provided, you’re talking about *column* names, not row names.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry everyone, I’ve updated my post to reflect properly.  Let’s get away from the colnames red-herring; my goal is I simply want to display the names per observation . “Observation1”, “Observation2”, “Observation3”

Comment: Also, when editing your code here please make sure the code actually works. You’ve repeated posted invalid code that used typographic quotes (`“…”`) that are invalid in R, instead of straight quotes (`"…"`). You probably also mean to use `c` instead of `list`. The latter works but makes no sense here.

Comment: Regarding your last edit: A **matrix** is not a data table. Neither `tibble` nor `data.frame` is a suitable data type to represent a matrix. *Use `matrix`*. That’s a different data structure, and using “tidy” data tools with it does not make sense.

Comment: As @KonradRudolph points out the documentation is very clear **It never uses row.names(). The whole point of tidy data is to store variables in a consistent way. So it never stores a variable as special attribute.** it warns you and you shouldn't be surprised its `print()` method doesn't honor them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I have upvoted your comments as the answers. I will happily accept them as the answers.

Comment: @ChuckP I have upvoted your comments as the answers. I will happily accept them as the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple facets to this.

First, [as the vignette explains](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/tibble.html), tibbles intentionally do not support row names because

> [t]he whole point of tidy data is to store variables in a consistent way. So it never stores a variable as special attribute.

The “tidy way” is to instead add another column that contains the name. In your case, this could be done, for instance, via

```
tib = tibble(Weight = c(120,130,140), Name = c("Jack", "John", "James")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Observation = paste("Observation", seq_len(dplyr::n())))
```

When pretty-printing the table most table printing libraries allow you to explicitly specify what data to use for the row names; for instance, [‘DT’ has the `rownames` parameter](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/#display-row-names).

But as your data contains a correlation matrix, **`tibble` (and `data.table`) is the wrong data type**. Matrices are not “tidy data tables”. Instead, they’re a specific [mathematical object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)), a special case of high-dimensional arrays/tensors. Tibbles (and data.frames) have special properties and operations defined for them which make no sense for matrices (such as different data types for different columns, and the fact that each column represents a different variable, and each row represents one observation). Conversely, matrices have properties and operations that are not meaningful and undefined for data tables (such as matrix multiplication, element-wise operations, transposition, inversion, etc.).

Since your data is a correlation matrix, store it as a `matrix`. You will then also be able to use row names.

Comment: Many thanks for helping answer so clearly. Apologies for typos and stuff in beginning.